# Does MySQL obtain a lock while adding a new ENUM value to an existing ENUM column?

Tags: mysql, database, enums

I have a MySQL table with one column as `ENUM`. Currently it has only two values, let's say `ENUM_1, ENUM_2`. Adding a new value to this list, i.e. adding `ENUM_3` is pretty straight forward.

```
ALTER TABLE
    my_db.my_table
MODIFY COLUMN
    `type` enum(
        'enum_1',
        'enum_2',
        'enum_3'
    )
```

The only concern I have is will MySQL obtain any kind of lock (read/write) on the table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not if you specify `ALGORITHM=INPLACE, LOCK=NONE;`

From the [Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-online-ddl-operations.html):

**Modifying the definition of an ENUM or SET column**

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (c1 ENUM('a', 'b', 'c'));
ALTER TABLE t1 MODIFY COLUMN c1 ENUM('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'), ALGORITHM=INPLACE, LOCK=NONE;
```

> Modifying the definition of an ENUM or SET column by adding new enumeration or set members to the end of the list of valid member values may be performed in place, as long as the storage size of the data type does not change. For example, adding a member to a SET column that has 8 members changes the required storage per value from 1 byte to 2 bytes; this requires a table copy. Adding members in the middle of the list causes renumbering of existing members, which requires a table copy.